# java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed in lollipop and marshmallow

Tags: android, android-camera, runtimeexception, camera-api

I am trying to make an app which takes front image then back image on a single activity intent, my front camera code is same as below and works perfectly fine i even call a finish to destroy the surface and inside onSurfaceDestroy() i call initBackCam() method given below which again works fine till onSurfaceChanged() inside onSurfaceChanged() i am calling pCamera.takePicture(null,mPictureCallback,mPictureCallback) which is throwing exception takePicture Failed

**Note:** This code works fine till kitkat it fails in lollipop and marshmallow

I tried delay in between front and back camera, i tried to put code for back camera in different activity still it throws the same error, i have released the camera and calling startPreview() before taking picture but still it throws the same error

**i have used following permissions**

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.back" android:required="false" />
```

PLEASE HELP!!!!

```
public static Bitmap bitmap;
public SurfaceHolder pSurfaceHolder;
private Camera pCamera;
private boolean pPreviewRunning = false;
private RelativeLayout pCameraPreview;
private BackCameraService backCam;

private void initBackCamera() {
    pCameraPreview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview_back_camera);
    backCam = new BackCameraService(getBaseContext(), pCamera);
    pCameraPreview.addView(backCam);
}

public class BackCameraService extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    public Camera pCamera;
    private Context pContext;

    Camera.PictureCallback mBackPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            pCamera = camera;
            if (data != null) {
                pCamera.stopPreview();
                pPreviewRunning = false;
                pCamera.release();

                try {
                    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    opts.inScaled = false;
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opts);
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(-90);
                    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyImage");
                    if (!(root.isDirectory() && root.exists())) root.mkdirs();
                    File backImg = new File(root.getAbsolutePath(), "backImg");
                    if (!(backImg.isDirectory() && backImg.exists())) backImg.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File(backImg.getAbsolutePath(), "backImage.jpg");
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                        ostream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                setResult(585);
            }
        }
    };

    BackCameraService(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        Log.d("jagteraho", "backCam started");
        pContext = context;
        pCamera = camera;
        pSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
        pSurfaceHolder.addCallback(BackCameraService.this);
        pSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        surfaceCreated(pSurfaceHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d("jagteraho", "backCam surface created");
        pCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        surfaceChanged(holder, 2, 2, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.d("jagteraho", "backCam surface changed");
        if (pPreviewRunning) {
            pCamera.stopPreview();
        }
        Camera.Parameters p = pCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(1);
        p.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
        try {
            pCamera.setParameters(p);
            pCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pCamera.startPreview();
        pPreviewRunning = true;
        pCamera.takePicture(null, mBackPictureCallback, mBackPictureCallback);
        surfaceDestroyed(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d("jagteraho", "backCam surface destroyed");
    }
}
```

**The Log is as follows:**

```
02-15 19:18:11.159 6382-6382  surface created
02-15 19:18:11.161 206-892/? I/CameraService﹕ CameraService::connect call (PID 6382 , camera ID 1) for HAL version default and Camera API version 1
02-15 19:18:11.222 206-892/? I/Camera2ClientBase﹕ Camera 1: Opened. Client: (PID 6382, UID 10037)
02-15 19:18:11.485 6382-6382 surface changed
02-15 19:18:11.553 779-800/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed  +473ms
02-15 19:18:13.849 206-818/? I/Camera2ClientBase﹕ Closed Camera 1. Client was:  (PID 6382, UID 10037)
02-15 19:18:14.102 6382-6382 ﹕ surface destroyed
02-15 19:18:14.103 6382-6382 ﹕ backCam started
02-15 19:18:14.103 6382-6382 ﹕ backCam surface created
02-15 19:18:14.103 206-1764/? I/CameraService﹕ CameraService::connect call (PID 6382 , camera ID 0) for HAL version default and Camera API version 1
02-15 19:18:14.165 206-1764/? I/Camera2ClientBase﹕ Camera 0: Opened. Client:(PID 6382, UID 10037)
02-15 19:18:14.238 6382-6382 ﹕ backCam surface changed
02-15 19:18:14.240 6382-6382 ﹕ app passed NULL surface
02-15 19:18:14.241 6382-6382 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-15 19:18:14.243 6382-6382 E/CustomActivityOnCrash﹕ App has crashed, executing CustomActivityOnCrash's UncaughtExceptionHandler
java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
        at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
        at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1434)
        at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1379)
        at com.aspeage.jagteraho.AlarmActivity$BackCameraService.surfaceChanged(AlarmActivity.java:922)
        at com.aspeage.jagteraho.AlarmActivity$BackCameraService.surfaceCreated(AlarmActivity.java:872)
        at com.aspeage.jagteraho.AlarmActivity$BackCameraService.<init>(AlarmActivity.java:865)
        at com.aspeage.jagteraho.AlarmActivity.initBackCamera(AlarmActivity.java:788)
        at com.aspeage.jagteraho.AlarmActivity.access$400(AlarmActivity.java:77)
        at com.aspeage.jagteraho.AlarmActivity$FrontCameraService.surfaceDestroyed(AlarmActivity.java:782)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:567)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:239)
        at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:9647)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1383)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

Add:

```
SurfaceTexture st = new SurfaceTexture(MODE_PRIVATE); 
pCamera.setPreviewTexture(st);
```

before:

```
pCamera.startPreview();
```

> [takePicture failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325733/takepicture-failed-in-lollipop)

Hope this will help u out

Comment: Thanks for replying, sorry I forgot to mention but I had tried this too, It gives me a warning "W/Camera-JNI﹕ callback on dead camera object" takePicture does not work and backCam image does not get generated I tried debugging it, but the flow just gets lost after takePicture() is called.

Comment: Hey, btw this worked for me but with a delay, I had to use delay in mBackPictureCallback, I think it takes some time to take the back camera picture anyways Thanks a lot @Strider

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day